# Oracle - Make one table with many columns or split in many tables

Tags: database, oracle

What is the best way to model a database? I have many known channels with values. Is it better create one table with many columns, one for each channel or create two table one for values and one for channels? Like that:

Table RAW_VALUES: SERIE_ID, CHANNEL_1, ..., CHANNEL_1000

or

Table RAW_VALUES: SERIE_ID, CHANNEL_ID, VALUE

Table CHANNELS: CHANNEL_ID, NAME, UNIT, ....

My question is about performance to search some data or save database space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, one would want to know what type of queries you will run against the tables as well as the data distribution etc to choose between two designs. However, I think that there are more fundamental issues here to guide you.

The second alternative is certainly more flexible.  Adding one more channel ("Channel_1001") can be done simply by inserting rows in the two tables (a simple DML operation), whereas if you use the first option, you need to add a column to the table (a DDL operation), and that will not be usable by any programs using this table unless you modify them.

That type of flexibility alone is probably a good reason to go with the second option.

Searching will also be better served with the second option. You may create one index on the raw_values table and support indexed searches on the Channel/Value columns.  (I would avoid the name "value" for a column by the way.)

Now if you consider what column(s) to index under the first option, you will probably be stumped: you have 1001 columns there.  If you want to support indexed searches on the values, would you index them all?  Even if you were dealing with just 10 channels, you would still need to index those 10 columns under your first option; not a good idea in general to load a table with more than a few indexes.

As an aside, if I am not mistaken, the limit is 1000 columns per table these days, but a table with more than 255 columns will store a row in multiple row pieces, each storing 255 columns and that would create a lot of avoidable I/O for each select you issue against this table.